# Issue with late version of selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium java project but I have an unsual error after some weeks not working on the project.

[image: error message]

[image: description]

After searching on internet, most people said it was related to the chrome driver version. This seems weid, because I use the "io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager" package to handle chrome version (and as you can see, I used the 103 chrome driver version).

After downloading the next version, and use:

"System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\path\webdriver\chromedriver-104.exe");" the browser even fail to open, and it print me this error message.

[image]

But it seems the version is still 103 for my "personnal" chrome browser. I tried to update it, but it remains 103..

[image]

[image]

I tried to download the 104, but it act "beta chrome"...

[image]

What am I supposed to? Is there anyone else having issue with chrome selenium lately? Is there a work around? Can someone explain why selenium even bother to know the version of my work chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is actually in version 103 of the *Chrome browser*, not *chromedriver*. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121 .

I have been able to mostly work around this by adding Thread.Sleep()'s (in C#) ranging from a fraction of a second to a few seconds, before the Selenium calls which fail.